# If $f:[0, t] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and has bounded variation, then its quadratic variation is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f:[0, t] \to \mathbb R$. For $n \in \mathbb N$, we define
$$
\begin{align}
V^{(1)}_{n} &:= \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \left|f\left(\frac{i t}{2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac{(i-1) t}{2^n}\right)\right|, \\
V^{(2)}_{n} &:= \sum_{i=1}^{2^n}\left(f\left(\frac{i t}{2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac{(i-1) t}{2^n}\right)\right)^2.
\end{align}
$$

Let $V^{(1)} = \lim_n V^{(1)}_{n}$ and $V^{(2)} = \lim_n V^{(2)}_{n}$ be the variation and quadratic variation of $f$ respectively. In proving that the standard Brownian motion has unbounded variation, I come across below result.

> **Theorem** If $f$ is continuous and $V^{(1)}  < +\infty$, then $V^{(2)} =0$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** Because $[0, t]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon$. There is $N>0$ such that $\frac{i t}{2^n} - \frac{(i-1) t}{2^n} = \frac{t}{2^n} < \delta$ for all $n\ge N$. Let
$$
y_i :=\left|f\left(\frac{i t}{2^N}\right)-f\left(\frac{(i-1) t}{2^N}\right)\right| \quad \forall i=1, \ldots, 2^N.
$$

Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2^N} y_i^2 \le \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^{2^N} y_i \bigg ) \max \{y_i : i=1, \ldots, 2^N\} \le V^{(1)} \varepsilon.
$$

The result then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof is fine.  I guess you've already shown that your expressions for $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(2)}$ actually give the variation and quadratic variation, respectively, for continuous functions then?  (in my opinion, the more general expression gives a nicer proof, but it's effectively the same as what you've written)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I thought the expressions for $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(1)}$ will give the variation and quadratic variation for arbitrary $f$ defined on a compact interval, no? It's because the width of each sub-interval will be arbitrary small when $n$ increases.

Comment: No.  For a simple example, consider $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(1/\pi) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Your expressions give $0$ for both the variation and the quadratic variation rather than the correct answer of $2$ for both.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you so much for your explanation! Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you've already shown your expression for $V^{(2)}$ actually gives the  quadratic variation of continuous functions, there's only one issue I see to your proof, and it's more a matter of clarity.

When you write
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^N} y_i^2 \le \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^{2^N} y_i \bigg ) \max \{y_i : i=1, \ldots, 2^N\} \le V^{(1)} \varepsilon$$
you have $N$ as a constant depending on $\varepsilon$, so letting $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ isn't as clean a step as we'd like it to be.  Instead, in the setup, you should probably have written
$$y_{i,n} :=\left|f\left(\frac{i t}{2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac{(i-1) t}{2^n}\right)\right| \quad \forall i=1, \ldots, 2^n$$
where $n \geq N$ is arbitrary.

Then the statement in question becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} y_{i,n}^2 \le \bigg (\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} y_{i,n} \bigg ) \max \{y_{i,n} : i=1, \ldots, 2^n\} \le V^{(1)} \varepsilon$$

The benefit here is that we may first let $n \to \infty$ to show that
$$V^{(2)} \leq V^{(1)}\varepsilon,$$
and now letting $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ to conclude has no possible issue.

---

To reiterate, you could justify letting $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ originally without my proposed changes, but you'd need to say more about it.  Otherwise, it may appear you're interchanging some limits, which is the source of one of many common errors in analysis.